# Why I get just one section when I use __EXPORT_SYMBOL

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel

As we know ,__EXPORT_SYMBOL is used when we want to export our symbols .
I found there is a macro in 
[exort.h](http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/include/linux/export.h)
As you can see it below:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_MODVERSIONS
/* Mark the CRC weak since genksyms apparently decides not to
 * generate a checksums for some symbols */
#define __CRC_SYMBOL(sym, sec)                  \
    extern void *__crc_##sym __attribute__((weak));     \
    static const unsigned long __kcrctab_##sym      \
    __used                          \
    __attribute__((section("___kcrctab" sec "+" #sym), unused)) \
    = (unsigned long) &__crc_##sym;
#else
#define __CRC_SYMBOL(sym, sec)
#endif
```

There is a line: "**attribute**((section("**_kcrctab" sec "+" #sym), unused))"
I believe it means that this variable(unsigned long _*kcrctab*##sym) will be placed in a special section ,whose name is ("**_kcrctab" sec "+" #sym).Doesn't it mean there would be a lot of sections in the final elf file?
But,I use readelf utility to check vmlinux and I found there is only one section.
__kcrctab_gpl.It's size is 0x3F40 .
Could you please help me. I am a new comer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They get mapped back into .rodata by the linker script.

From the arm version: ./arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds

```
    __kcrctab : AT(ADDR(__kcrctab) - 0) {
       __start___kcrctab = .;
       *(SORT(___kcrctab+*)) __stop___kcrctab = .;
    }
```

There are a lot of things going on in those linker scripts, but the basic idea here is that everything which lives in a '__kcrctab+*' section gets put into __kcrctab.